# ng-class and css on tr ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to color my rows according to a certain value.

HTML :

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: u | orderBy:orderProperty" ng-class="{'added': user.status === 'added'}">
</tr>
```

CSS :

```
.added {
background-color : green;
color: white;
}
```

My CSS is applied for every rows for the property `color:white` which is coloring the text in white but my CSS is applied once on 2 rows for the property `background-color:green`

I got the same problem by using a simple class instead of ng-class :

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: u | orderBy:orderProperty" class="added">
</tr>
```

My JSON schema for users :

```
  [
          {
            name : 'Toto',
            age : '',
            tel : '****',
            hobbies : 'basket'
          },...
   ]
```

There is something like 1000 users and 20 properties for each ones.

Comment: what's your `users`, what's your filter `u`? please provide more details

Comment: It's just data that I display using AngularJS, I don't think my problem is link to that.

Comment: @Tewan Can you provide your JSON data `users`?

Comment: can u elaborate **CSS is only working one row in two for the background-color.** orr add the screenshot

Comment: are you sure you do not have only one user with `status === 'added'` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working demo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{
    name: 'Carlos',
    status: 'added'
  }, {
    name: 'Jean',
    status: 'new'
  }, {
    name: 'Paul',
    status: 'added'
  }];
}]);
```

```css
.added {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class="{'added': user.status === 'added'}">
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
       <td>{{user.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it possible using `<tr>` instead of `<div>` ?

Comment: @Tewan Updated to use a table/tr/td instead of div.

Comment: I tried your solution but it still alternating rows for the `background-color`, I think i'm going to color every `<td>` instead of the whole `<tr>`

Comment: @Tewan I can't reproduce your issue. As you can see, it works well on my demo. :)

Comment: I'm using AngularJS 1.6.3, could it be the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Use as follow

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in user | orderBy : ol" ng-class='{added : user.status == "added"}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: u | orderBy:orderProperty" ng-class="user.status === 'added' ? 'added' : '' ">
```

> ng-class="user.status === 'added' ? 'added' : ' ' "

Comment: Not working :/ I also tried by using a simple `class=""` instead of `ng-class` but it's the same problem

Comment: can you share the code which is inside the table tag and also try to print the user object if the data is correct  <pre>{{ user | json }}</pre>